# Show the message "N/A" if the $row['gate'] is empty

Tags: php, logic

I need to show the message "N/A" if the $row['gate'] is empty. Is it possible to do this using logical symbols `":","?"` ?

Comment: Why not `echo empty($row['gate'])?'N/A':$row['gate']` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
echo (isset($row['gate']) && !empty($row['gate'])) ? $row['gate'] : 'N/A';
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP 5.3+ allows you to do this.

`echo $row['gate'] ?: 'N/A';`

That will essentially 'coalesce' an empty value to 'N/A' but if it has a value, it will echo the value.

Comment: Note that this still emits an e_notice if `$row["gate"]` is not defined.

Comment: From the OP, he asked if the variable was empty so I presume it's defined.

Answer (score 1):

[Ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) is commonly used for this kind of validation.

Example while using phps [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)-function:

```
$output = (!empty($row['gate'])) ? $row['gate'] : 'N/A';
var_dump($output);
```

(This ofc only checks if the variable is empty, like asked. If you want to check if the variable is defined, use a [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) in there, too).

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible with ternary operator

```
isset($row['data']) ? "your_value" : "N/A";
```

This is the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's possible

```
<?php
 $row = array();
 echo (empty($row['gate'])) ? 'N/A' : $row['gate'];
?>
```